# TFS Cube - Total Lines of Code appears incorrect?

Tags: tfs

I'm using the TFS cube [as documented here](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/getting_started.html) and am getting a curious result for 'total lines'.  If I look at a file inside of visual studio, I see that a file is perhaps 42 lines long (total, comments, whitespace, and all).  However, when I ask the TFS cube for that same information, it tells me that the file is almost - but not exactly - twice its size.

I have my pivot table set up as follows:

- Report Filter includes a specific team project, and is filtered on file extension (.cs)
- Row labels set to Filename.Parent_ID
- Values set to 'Total Lines'

I've looked at the MSDN guidance [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244698%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and can't see what I've done wrong, other than noting that I have not selected an individual build (if i do so, I get no results).

Edit: As it may be relevant, I'm using TFS 2008 SP1 with SQL 2005 standard. There is a note on the MSDN page which cautions me that SQL 2005 Standard does not support perspectives, and 'the cube elements from all perspectives reside in the team system data cube'.  I'm not  sure what that means for this problem, if anything.

Answer (score 1):

Check your linebreaks in the files : does numbers change if you convert files between windows/linux line endings?

Please add lines with 60, 90, 150, 200 characters and check how many added lines will be reported. Might be some work-wrapping.